# Choosing which line to display based on a set of criteria

Tags: c#, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am doing continuing development on a project that is giving me a lot of trouble. First off, I do not know how to use Entity Framework, but I know database design, and looking through this database is giving me headaches because it is not normalized. I'm not sure if that's the fault of Entity Framework or the previous developer.

Let's say I have this table:

```
ForeignKey    Product     Manufacturing     Completed
--            -------     -------------     ---------
01            Shoes       Step A            2020-02-24 00:00:00.0000000
02            Shirt       Step A            2020-02-25 00:00:00.0000000
03            Pants       Step A            2020-02-25 00:00:00.0000000
01            Shoes       Step B            2020-02-24 13:56:00.0000000
02            Shirt       Step B            NULL
03            Pants       Step B            2020-02-25 13:11:00.0000000
04            Hat         Step B            NULL
04            Hat         Step A            NULL
```

I need to get back the following set of results:

```
ForeignKey    Product     Manufacturing     Completed
--            -------     -------------     ---------
01            Shoes       Step B            2020-02-24 13:56:00.0000000
02            Shirt       Step B            NULL
03            Pants       Step B            2020-02-25 13:11:00.0000000
04            Hat         Step A            NULL
```

I'm not an expert with SQL, so this is giving me a lot of trouble. I need to meet the following criteria:

1. Return the row that is furthest along in the manufacturing process. This means that sometimes the completed dates of both rows will be null(I'll need to return the row of Step A), sometimes the first step completed date will be complete but the second's will be null(in which case I'll need to return Step B because it is done with the first step), and sometimes they will both have completed dates, in which case I'll need to return Step B.
2. Step A and Step B were chosen for clarity of this question, in reality the name of step A comes alphabetically after step B, so an alphabetical sort won't work.

This has me pulling my hair out. Help!

Comment: Why do you want to get "Step A" for the "Hat"?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using.

Comment: How many things have you left out? You state Step A and Step B aren't the actual values, are the actual values still strings? Is there a Step C? If no, can we sort alphabetically descending? If yes, do we have access to another table that contains the actual order of operations?

Comment: I want to get step A for the hat because step A is not marked as completed which means it has not moved to step B so is still currently in step A.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
select *
from (
    select
        t.*,
        rank() over(
            partition by foreignkey 
            order by 
                case when completed is null then 0 else 1 end, 
                completed desc, 
                manufacturing
       ) rn
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 1
order by foreignkey
```

The logic resides in the `order by` clause of the window function: this puts records whose `completed` is `null` first, then sorts by descending `completed` (if any), and finally by ascending `manufacturing`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=bda53534b2a69d06981519bd064ab1df)**:

```
foreignkey | product | manufacturing | completed                   | rn
---------: | :------ | :------------ | :-------------------------- | -:
         1 | Shoes   | Step B        | 2020-02-24 13:56:00.0000000 |  1
         2 | Shirt   | Step B        | null                        |  1
         3 | Pants   | Step B        | 2020-02-25 13:11:00.0000000 |  1
         4 | Hat     | Step A        | null                        |  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize pivot to summarize steps and then use an easier decision making like:

```
with pvt as (
select * from myTable 
pivot (
  max(completed) for Manufacturing in ([Step A], [Step B])
) tmp
)
select ForeignKey, Product,
   case 
   when [Step A] is null and [Step B] is null then 'Step A' 
   else 'Step B' end as Manufacturing,
   case 
   when [Step A] is not null or [Step B] is not null then [Step B] end as Completed
from pvt
order by foreignKey;
```

[DbFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=99a8799749a163adb12ab3ca5dec08ce)